# ucommerce custom pipeline configs not working

Tags: config, pipeline, umbraco-ucommerce

I've added and removed pipeline tasks from the Basket.config and Custom.config but whatever I do nothing happens. Even if I remove the files, the previously registered custom pipeline tasks are excecuted.

I don't understand why. What do I have to do to be able to edit these files and make the changes excecute?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

another thing to be aware of here is that if your application finds old configuration sets (depending on your uCommerce version) old configuration could be picked up. uCommerce automatically picks up "components.config" by scanning the website to find it. If, for some reason (usually VS publish) there's another set of confiuration files, that could unintentionally be picked up.

This was fixed in version **6.1.1.14217**.
But as martin suggests, recycling the app pool is most likely the cause!

Hope this helps you. 
Best regards
Morten

Answer (score 0):

When you add/remove pipeline components in any of uCommerce's configuration files you have to recycle your application pool since uCommerce is only reading these configuration files on website startup/spinup.